# android: get object with specific name from arraylist

Tags: android, search, arraylist, filter

I have an arraylist of custom objects (ArrayList al1) which is loaded into a listview lv1. There is also another listview lv2 filled with another arraylist (al2) with the same objects.

Now when the user clicks on one of these items in lv2, I need to get the object from al1 with the name (field in the custom object) of the object in lv2.

So instead of accessing the item with getItem(int position), I want to look for the item by name.

The custom object looks like this:

```
public class Cover {

    private String path = null;
    private String name = null;
    private byte[] coverBytes = null;
    private ArrayList<Cover> subList = null;

    ... and getters/setters
}
```

The ArrayList subList in class Cover is used for populating a third listview lv3, when user clicks on lv1

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `SimpleAdapter` or an `ArrayAdapter<Cover>`.

Comment: yea that's what I'm using for populating the list but how to get an object by name?

Comment: You could impement your own by wrapping around `getItemAtPosition`.